# Carrying NSUserdefaults information from one viewcontroller to another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication

I'm currently working on a simple app, one to really test my skills and understanding of xcode and app development. I'm still a beginner so it's primarily a learning tool as well as skill building. Either way, I'm trying to implement a simple login/register before going on to the next view controller screen with the login and register screen being separate and information stored in the app, not to pharse or icloud.

In ViewController1.m, i call for ViewController2.h:

```
#import "ViewController2.h"
```

This is also done in ViewController2.m for ViewController1.h.

In ViewController1.m i utilize NSUserDefaults as such:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standarUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:_usernameField2.text forKey:@"username"];
[defaults setObject:_passwordField2.text forKey:@"password"];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey@"registered"];

[defaults synchronize];
```

When running the program and i am able to register the user and through segue command i'm able to go to the next view controller:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginScreen" sender:self];
```

Ideally when I access the ViewController2 screen I want to use the information from the previous viewcontroller (ViewController1). However, when i attempt to use the information stored the program doesn't acknowledge the information from the previous viewController.

```
-(void) checkCredintials
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (![_usernameField1.text isEqualToString:[defaults objectForKey:@"username"]] && ![_passwordField1.text isEqualToString:[defaults objectForKey:@"password"]])
```

I've tried other methods such as using NSString however I believe i'm either missing something simple or how i'm attempting to implement the code may be off. Part of me thinks it might be due to the fact that I am running and coding on a later version of xcode (4.6.3) but that's a minuet thought. I've done research and i've tried a few ways, just not sure what i'm missing or what i might need to add or change up. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Your question doesn't say what the problem is. "doesn't acknowledge the information" is meaningless and that if statement you have posted does nothing at all to tell us what the actual problem is. What are you expecting or wanting to happen at that line and what are you observing? If usernameField1 is a member of the second view controller as well as the first, then where/how is it getting its data from? If that code is not view controller 2 then why are you showing it.

Comment: You don't want to store credentials in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: I guess i didnt really express the problem but what I'm trying to achieve is when the user types in their information on the register screen (username and password) that in View Controller 1 its saved in NSUserdefaults. What i'm trying to do is recall that saved information that i placed in NSUserdefaults from ViewController 1 to the defaults in ViewController 2 for username and password.Overall, i'm trying to use whatever I saved in the first ViewController (username and password) for the second view controller. Im also unsure if I may have my if statement wrong in what im trying to check

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint or NSLog the values of the textfields and what is stored for the keys in defaults in checkCredintails method. Also just check that you're actually saving values for _usernameField2 and _passwordField2.

The way you save and retrieve data from NSUserDefaults looks fine, so the user enters(saves) they username and password in ViewController1 and enter it again in ViewController2 to get it verified? You probably shouldn't use NSUserDefaults to check/store passwords, but I guess you're just doing this as an example.